# Syntax Error in Assigning a Value to a Variable

Tags: python, variables

I am making a program with python that involves defining a function that looks a bit like this:

```
def GetNumbers(): 

print('What is the coefficient of x^2?')
global xsqurd = int(input)
```

But when I call this function it returns a syntax error and says that the '=' is invalid syntax. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

```
def GetNumbers():
    global xsqurd
    xsqurd = int(input('What is the coefficient of x^2? '))
```

Note that for Python 2.x you'd have to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: Note that if the OP is using python 3.x, this would be `input`, not `raw_input`.  It looks like they are using 3.x because of the parentheses around the `print`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global.  It's almost always a bad solution.  Consider returning a value instead.  That said, here's why you're seeing that error.

`global` is part of a statement that just takes that keyword and a name.  To use `global`, you need to split it out.

```
global xsqurd
xsqurd = int(input)
```

This assumes, of course, that input is some other global variable.  As Claudiu pointed out below, you most likely meant to call `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you did wrong was write something that isn't valid syntax.

A [`global`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt) statement just takes a sequence of variables names and declares them to be global. You can't throw random other syntax into it.

If you were trying to declare `xsqurd` to be global, and also update it in the same statement, there's no way to do that. Just write two statements:

```
global xsqurd
xsqurd = int(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
xsqurd = None
def GetNumbers(): 
    print('What is the coefficient of x^2?')
    global xsqurd
    xsqurd = int(22)

GetNumbers()
print xsqurd
```

Note the `global xsqurd` statement comes before the assignment.

Comment: While this does answer how to do what the OP wants, I think it's important that the OP know that in python, if you find yourself using globals you have almost certainly not designed your program well.

Comment: This option does not allow me to input values except manually - by changing the program every time I want to change the input. It completely ruins the idea of asking whoever runs the program, except as a bizarre guessing game... However, the global xsqurd was helpful, and I appreciate the prompt response.

Comment: Sorry, I was just simplifying to highlight the syntax error problem.  If you would like an example of getting input from the user, I can modify the example above.

Comment: @SethMMorton: Perhaps I should included a footnote (and I'll do better in the future), but I have written questions on this forum many times, simplifying my example code in such a way that it's difficult for others to see '_why_' I would do something a certain way.  I don't see this forum as a place to answer (or question) the '_why_' so much as the '_what_'.  I try not to make too many assumptions from someone's example code about how they are going to use the answer they get.  But you're right, it's more responsible to help with the '_why_' when it seems likely others will benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do a good job showing what you how to properly use `global` in the context you want.  If you really want to use globals, look at those answers.

I would argue, however, that this is not the most pythonic solution and will become difficult to use if your program becomes large.  You probably want a solution more like this:

```
def GetNumbers(): 
    val = input('What is the coefficient of x^2?')
    return int(val)

def myOtherFunction(x):
    return x**2 # Or whatever would be in this function

xsqurd = GetNumbers()
print xsqurd

# Using arguments to pass this to other functions
val = myOtherFunction(xsqurd)
```

This illustrates passing and returning variables from a function, and is the preferred way to do this.  Note that I have corrected some of your syntax errors and misunderstanding of how the input key works.

Comment: Absolutely correct, but I am using xsqurd in other functions I define later in the program. Thanks for the style tip though.

Comment: @user2218101 In that case, you would pass that variable as an argument to other functions. Take a look at my update.  I promise, if your program gets too big you will wish you had not used globals.